# Spring integration: Best way to implement retry for remote HTTP calls

Tags: spring-integration

I have channel with queue and it has several messages.
All of them should go to the remote system via http-outbound-gateway

If remote system is not available where do my message go? To the nowhere?
How can I retry later? Does there is something like "error-channel" for http-outbound-gateway?

PS:
I found way I probably like: using transactional chain + PseudoTransactionManager. It works.
But could I do it with less XML?

Answer (score 2):

See this biog post and the associated sample for using the MessageHandlerRetryAdvice...

http://spring.io/blog/2012/10/09/what-s-new-in-spring-integration-2-2-part-4-retry-and-more

After the retries as exhausted you can send the message to a `<delayer/>` and then send it through again.

Comment: is any similar solution in spring integration 2.1 available?

Comment: It can be done, but it's quite a bit more complex, with the details depending on exactly what your requirements are - it would certainly be easier to upgrade to 2.2.x.

Comment: Ok, could you point me to a solution for 2.1, even to a more complex one? Upgrade to 2.2 is not an option for me. I need to use a http-outbound-gateway to retrieve a web page content and want to retry a couple times before giving up. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gist here https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/6393239 hopefully self-explanatory.