# Mule ESB- How to handle ConnectException from remote Web Service

Tags: mule

I call a remote web service deployed on a server. However the service is unavailable sometimes. I want to capture the original message on that occasion and save it to a file. However, the message complains that it of type PostMethod.

```
<vm:inbound-endpoint path="receiver.in" name="AWS-Service"/>
<custom-transformer ref="byte-to=lfd-format"/>
<http:outbound address="https://advent-ws:9001/lfs-api" content-type="text/plain"/>
<default-exception-strategy>
<choice>
<when expression="#[exception.causedBy(java.lang.ConnectException)]">
  Here get transformed payload and send to file
</when>
...
</default-exception-strategy>
```

I tried using an expression-transformer but got the error message "org.mule.api.expression.."
That said Message Payload is of type PostMethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the Payload reaches the exception strategy block, the Message has already been consumed.

So you could store the payload in a variable before the service call and if you throw the exception you can read the original payload value, then write to file.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but Mule does try to reconnect to the endpoint a number of times. My goal is that once connecting to the service fails the first time, just save to file and we're done. Can this be done?

Comment: @BreenDee see if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753476/spring-integration-best-way-to-implement-retry-for-remote-http-calls